# How to reload Bada application without restarting the emulator?

Tags: emulation, reload, bada

Is it possible, and if yes then please tell me how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [confirmed](http://developer.bada.com/forum/topic.php?id=791) by bada team, this is not possible.

Comment: I can't view the link, but I trust you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In bada 2.0 it works normaly, one time you start the emulator and after you can multiple 
change code and run/debug application.

Only one thing you must do, kill the app before uploading new version into emulator, this you do when click the right button on emulator.

Comment: This response is correct, killing the app on the device first (or by hitting stop from debug perspective, in the debug view, you can run the next build without killing the emulator, works on 2.0.2 and 2.0.4 as tested. I havn't tested earlier SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to click the call termination button on the emulator and you can run the app again